# ES6 Inject in an extended class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am curious can I call a extended class and have it still import the things it needs specifically.

Welcome Class:

```
import { ErrorLevel } from './error-level.js';

export class Welcome extends ErrorLevel {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}
```

Error-Level Class:

```
import { Notification } from 'aurelia-notification';

export class ErrorLevel {
  static inject() {
    return [Notification];
  }

  constructor(notification) {
    this.notification = notification;
  }
}
```

I know once I call `super()` it will call the extended class and pass in 0 arguments. Is there a way for my ErrorClass constructor to pull in Notification when I call `super()`?

Comment: How about `constructor(notification) { super(notification); }`?

Comment: i knew about this, injecting notification at the welcome class and then passing it to the extended class. was wondering if there was a way around that

Comment: Who is "injecting" anything here anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `super([arguments]); // calls the parent constructor.`
>   `super.functionOnParent([arguments]);`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super

Passing an argument in Welcome's `super` function calls the parent class constructor with that argument. You will see the log of `this` contains notification which is set to the argument we pass into super.

http://jsbin.com/raguqopesu/1/edit?js,console,output

```
class ErrorLevel {
  constructor(notification) {
    this.notification = notification;
  }
}


class Welcome extends ErrorLevel {
  constructor() {
    super(Notification);
    console.log(this);
  }
}


const yo = new Welcome();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export class Welcome extends ErrorLevel {
  constructor(notification) {
    super(notification);
  }
}
```